# Swagger Server stub generation workflow

Tags: java, spring, jpa, swagger

My Spring boot Rest API development workflow looks as follows:

1. Create/Update Swagger specification
2. Generation of server stubs (Api interfaces, controller, model classes)
3. Implementing stubs

Now I am using JPA annotations in my model classes. Extending models in the swagger specification would now generate new model classes with the newly added attributes. But I prevent the server stub generator from overwriting my model classes since I have customized them with my Annotations.

How can I integrate the model class generation in my workflow to get the newly specified attribute without having to rewrite my model classes' annotations?

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Extend all model classes in own package and then just annotate the attributes as you want to.

e.g. /models/account.java -> extends to -> /models/ext/account.java

Then overwriting the model classes doesn't affect the JPA annotations in the extended classes.